# autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required

Tags: configure, autoreconf

I followed the instructions to install [FB Machine Learning tools.](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/233310_e86d8aa8a63e45da8c8f5da3b1bc058d.html)

One of the libraries installation instructions are

```
cd ~/libraries
git clone https://github.com/facebook/folly.git
cd folly/folly/
autoreconf -ivf
./configure
cp -R ~/libraries/gtest-1.7/* ./test/gtest-1.7/
make
make check
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig # reload the lib paths after freshly installed folly. fbthrift needs it.
```

I have problem at `autoreconf -ivf`, the error is

```
autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required
```

But when I install autoreconf, I have the newest version.

```
autoconf is already the newest version (2.69-9).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: It's not about the autoreconf version, it's about the fact that you need one of the original configure.ac/in files. Are they present?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher So you mean the file `configure.ac` or `configure.in` is supposed to be in folly/folly folder. But I can't find such file in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`folly` is not using the `autotols` anymore, but CMake (there is only a `CMakeLists.txt`  file, not `configure.*`).

See here for the steps: https://github.com/facebook/folly#dependencies

Comment: i am trying to install it on ubuntu 14;04 - which still gives me the error ... i appreciate if you update your answer with more clarificiation - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Installing `pkgconf` package fixed it for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

error: `autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required`

Just don't try to install.

In most cases the `autoreconf -i` command helps, but it did not work for you due to an inappropriate package :\

In your case will be adequately to look at the documentation for installation from the terminal to your OS.